# Stock checker code is not working, it has one error and will not complile

Tags: c#

I am trying to run this code as a fun project. I am running into an error. Can anyone help me getting this running?

The error is on this line:

```
_httpClient ??= new HttpClient
```

The error in the compiler:

> mcs -out:main.exe main.cs main.cs(45,30): error CS1525: Unexpected
> symbol `=' Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 0 warnings compiler exit
> status 1

Can anyone please help me fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;

namespace Ps5Watcher
{
public class Program
{
    [ThreadStatic] private static HttpClient _httpClient;

    private static readonly Random Rng = new Random();

    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Func<HtmlDocument, bool>> SiteRules =
        new Dictionary<string, Func<HtmlDocument, bool>>
        {
            {
                "https://www.walmart.com/ip/Sony-PlayStation-5-Digital-Edition/493824815",
                doc => !doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
                    .Any(node =>
                        node.HasClass("prod-blitz-copy-message") && node.InnerText.Contains("out of             
 stock"))
            }
        };

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var checkInterval = new Timer(1000);
        checkInterval.Elapsed += CheckSites;
        checkInterval.Start();

        while (!Console.ReadLine()?.Equals("stop", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ??     
  true)
        {
        }
    }

    private static void CheckSites(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var site in SiteRules)
        {
            _httpClient ??= new HttpClient
            {
                DefaultRequestHeaders =
                    {{"User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 
      Firefox/78.0"}}
            };

            Thread.Sleep(Rng.Next(50, 2000));

            // load the html document
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(_httpClient.GetStreamAsync(site.Key).GetAwaiter().GetResult());

            // check our rule for this site and report the results
            var host = new Uri(site.Key).Host;
            if (site.Value(doc))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow:s} ({host}) - Available!");

                // open the page immediately
                Process.Start(site.Key);

                // stop the timer so that we don't keep opening the page
                ((Timer)sender).Stop();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTimeOffset.UtcNow:s} ({host}) - Not in stock");
            }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: [The null-coalescing assignment operator is available from C#8 on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator). What is your C# version?

Answer (score 3):

The null coalescing assignment is available starting with C# 8.0. You can replace it by

```
if (_httpClient == null) _httpClient = new HttpClient...
```

Comment: removed the line and added that, now I am getting:  main.cs(45,70): error CS1001: Unexpected symbol `.', expecting identifier
main.cs(46,17): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement
main.cs(48,24): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `{'
main.cs(48,38): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `,', expecting `;' or `}'
main.cs(48,109): error CS1002: ; expected
Compilation failed: 4 error(s), 1 warnings
compiler exit status 1

Comment: @user450157: Remove the three dots at the end of the line

Answer (score 0):

[`??=` is available since C# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator). If your project is not .NET Core 3.X or .NET 5 or .NET Standard 2.1 then you [can't use this operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8).

In such case you should go with proposition from @Henrik.

Comment: Tried replacing it and I am now getting:                                                                                             main.cs(8,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtmlAgilityPack' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
main.cs(15,39): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HttpClient' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
main.cs(19,57): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `HtmlDocument' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 3 error(s), 0 warnings
compiler exit status 1

Comment: Did you add `HtmlAgilityPack` nuget? This is different issue, probably for different question.